# php script to read xml data on remote unix server

Tags: php, xml, ssh, remote-server

I got a situation where I have lots of system configurations/logs off which I have to generate a quick review of the system useful for troubleshooting.

At first I'd like to build kind of web interface(most probably a php site) that gives me the rough snapshot of the system configuration using the available information from support logs. The support logs reside on mirrored servers (call it log server) & the server on which I'll be hosting the site (call it web server) will have to ssh/sftp to access them.

My rough sketch:

1. The php script on web server will make some kind of connection to the log server & go to the support logs location.
2. It'll then trigger a perl script at logs server, which will collect relevant stuffs from all the config/log files into some useful xml (there'd be multiple of those).
3. Someway these xml files are transferred to web server & php will use it to create the html out of it.

I'm very new to php & would like to know if this is feasible or if there's any other alternative/better way of doing this?
It would be great if someone could provide more details for the same.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Sorry I missed to mention that the logs aren't the ones generated on live machine, I'm dealing with sustenance activities for NAS storage device & there'll be plenty of support logs coming from different end customers which folks from my team would like to have a look at.
Security is not a big concern here (I'm ok with using plain text authentication to log servers) as these servers can be accessed only through company's VPN.

Comment: No need for PHP. just have the perl script do the xml generation->html transformation and then push that html out to your webserver on a scheduled basis.

Comment: thanks Marc for the reply.
As I mentioned gathering useful data is just first step towards relieving troubleshooting process, I would like to front end UI to be more interactive later on so I'm bit inclined towards PHP.

Also I can't host the site on the log servers itself.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this using something like [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (I think there is something for PHP too..), I would recommend doing this in two separate steps:

1. A script, running via Cron, retrieves data from servers and store it locally
2. The PHP script reads from the local stored data only, in order to generate reports.

This way, you have these benefits:

- You don't have to worry about how to make your php script connect via ssh to servers
- You avoid the security risks related to allowing your webserver user log in to other servers (high risk in case your script gets hacked)
- In case of slow / absent connectivity to servers, long time to retrieve logs, etc. you php script will still be able to quickly show the data -- maybe, along with some error message explaining what went wrong during latest update
- In any case, you php script will terminate much quicker since it only has to retrieve data from local storage.

### Update: ssh client via php

Ok, from your latest comment I understand that what you need is more a "front-end browser" to display the files, than a report generation tool or similar; in this case you can use [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (as I stated before) in order to connect to remote machines.

There is a PECL extension for PHP providing expect functionality. Have a look at the [PHP Expect manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php) and in particular at the [usage examples](http://php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php), showing how to use it to make SSH connections.

### Alternate way: taking files from NFS/SAMBA share

Another way, avoiding to use SSH, is to browse files on the remote machines via locally-mounted share.
This is expecially useful in case interesting files are already shared by a NAS, while I wouldn't recommend this if that would mean sharing the whole root filesystem or huge parts of it.

Comment: I'm not interested in doing cron activities, sorry I didn't made it clear in my earlier post.

Comment: What's wrong with cron? In any case, if I understood the question correctly, so you have "some files on remote servers" that you want to analyze to display a result I would do the two things in separate steps: 1. retrieve data and store locally, 2. analyze data and store result, 3. display data from processed results. Doing the three things each time you load the page will take very long time to generate page / high risk that something gets timed out during the process. That's why I suggested using a separate "data collector" script, running periodically.

Comment: thanks for your time, redShadow.
I don't need a cron here it's whole different problem as we have to deal with lots of log(ones generated by different NAS systems) directories with hundreds of files in it (compressed size around 10-100MB) so I'm not really interested in copying all those stuffs locally instead I'd generate/transfer only the data(like xml) useful for display by using some scripting at log server.
I'm concerned how easily this transfer of files from remote log server to web server could be done?

Comment: Ok, now I understood what you are looking for. See answer updates

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP can process XML. A simple way is to use SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php